# Include specific js script for responsive web design

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design

I'd like to know how to import a specific JS script for my mobile device...

Something like this :

```
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="stylesheets/bottom.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/normalize-css/normalize.css">
    <link href="stylesheets/app.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    // Only for media screen and (max-width : 500px)
    <script src="modile.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<script>
   if (window.screen.width <= 560) {
       // load the script you need
   } else {
       // load another script
   }
</script>
```

You can load scripts using jQuery getScript for example;